# Running SQL Server queries from remote computer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I am novice to SQL Server and Database also.

we have SQL Server 2008 installed on server.

I want to run queries from remote computer on the database which is resides in SQL Server 2008.

I want know that is there any tool/utility so I can install it on my local machine and run queries over database server.

Any alternate approach would be helpful.

Comment: You mean another tool than MS SQL Management Studio?

Comment: yes. millions of tools. try a simple gooogle search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If SQL Server 2008 is already installed in the server that you want to run the query you just need SQL Server Management Studio (Query analyzer). Just create a connection with the server and you will be able to run any query.

You can take the control of the server with other tools like TeamViewer and run queries with sqlcmd (from command prompt), query analyzer, or any others like [queryexpress](http://www.albahari.com/queryexpress.aspx) and many others if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL Server Management Studio and connect (By the name or IP of your server) to your remote server and run your sql